# Dexie.js seems to consume more space than necessary

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

We are using `Dexie.js` to save some binary data client-side. The binary data can be from 5-20MB.

The strange thing is when we download a file, much more space is consumed than the file size itself.

For example, downloading an `8.5MB` file results in a Dexie DB of `57MB` is this normal?

I ask because before long our users have downloaded a few files of around 100MB total and chrome will crash with an indexeddb of over 1GB.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Okay, so I have realised what the issue was. I had set an index on the binary data field. I think this had led to some serious overhead. Setting the index was a mistake I have removed it and now storing the 8.5MB file results in 11.4MB of storage used.

Comment: Great you found it. This seems to be a common mistake that I've heard that many other people have done. I updated the dexie landing page some year ago, and the get started samples so they should be more clear about the fact that not all fields should be indexed.